# Writing a SQL to calculate DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I have a table called `Hotel` and it has 3 columns `hotid`, `hotname` and `year`. I have get the date difference using the year. The SQL for that is as follows (and it works)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-08-04',NOW()) / -365 as Date_Value_Table ;
```

Now, i need to write an SQL that will list all the columns (records) from the `Hotel` table with another column called `Date_Value_Table` that takes the `year` column from the `Hotel table` and do a `DATEDIFF` as shown in above.

So basically i need a SQL that list all the records from the `Hotel` table and another column that does a `DATEDIFF` using the `Year` column from the `Hotel` table and to list all the records.

And i am using MySQL as my DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you mean this, but here it is:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(year,NOW()) / -365 as Date_Value_Table FROM Hotel
```

Comment: @Illep: Great! If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it. :)

Comment: I have to wait for 7 minutes to accept it and there's 1 minute more for it :D

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or I do not understand the question, or what you need is just this?

```
select hotid, hotname, year, DATEDIFF(year,NOW()) / -365 as Date_Value_Tabl
from Hotel
```